# draw rectangle when pixel in video has specific value using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My question might seem a bit confusing but what I want is simply to look at a specific pixel value and when it has the value eg. (25,25,25) in rgb, it would use the drawbox filter to draw a rectangle somewhere else in the video.

Having read the ffmpeg documentation I found that drawbox has timeline editing capabilities but it can only use the following values

‘t’
timestamp expressed in seconds, NAN if the input timestamp is unknown

‘n’
sequential number of the input frame, starting from 0

‘pos’
the position in the file of the input frame, NAN if unknown

‘w’
‘h’
width and height of the input frame if video

So is there a way to achieve what I want using drawbox or maybe another filter like geq?